# sqlite database not updating modified data in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Well i am new to iphone coding and using sqlite in one of my application the problem is my sqlite database does not updates the modified data, i am following a sqlite based tutorial:

this is what i am doing:-

```
- (void) saveAllData {

 if(isDirty) {


  if(updateStmt == nil) {
   const char *sql = "update Work Set Engagement = ?, Status = ?, Where WorkID = ?";
   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
  }

  sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [Engagement UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
  sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [Status UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   //sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 2, [Status doubleValue]);
  sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3, WorkID);
  //int Success = sqlit3_step(updateStmt);


  if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
   NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

  sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);

  isDirty = NO;
 }
```

i am using :

```
- (IBAction) save_Clicked:(id)sender {


 //Update the value.
 //Invokes the set<key> method defined in the Work Class.
 [objectToEdit setValue:txtField.text forKey:self.keyOfTheFieldToEdit];
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

for save button click  and :

```
- (void) setEngagement:(NSString *)newValue {

 self.isDirty = YES;
 [Engagement release];
 Engagement = [newValue copy];
}

- (void) setStatus:(NSString *)newNumber {

 self.isDirty = YES;
 [Status release];
 Status = [newNumber copy];
}
```

for setting values, i banged my head thousand times and can not find what i am doing wrong can some body plz help me with this.....

this is the code for my getDBPath implementation

```
- (NSString *) getDBPath {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CheckList.sqlite"];
}
```

this code for my Data Base :
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 

if(!success) {

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CheckList.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

    if (!success) 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is the path to `database`? The most common reason for not saving is that the database file has not been moved to the user's documents directory.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785211/sqlite3-database-doesnt-actually-insert-data-iphone

Comment: i think i have done it as i can insert data in the database but can't modify it..

Comment: this what i did .. in my code:

- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {
 
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSError *error;
 NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
 BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 
 
 if(!success) {
  
  NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CheckList.sqlite"];
  success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
  
  if (!success) 
   NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
 } 
}

Comment: Please update the question with your code instead adding as a comment. Add the implementation for `getDBPath` as well.

Comment: where do you call `-(void) saveAllData`?

Comment: i call it when the application is going to terminate in

Comment: - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
 [self.WorkArraymakeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(saveAllData)];

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show opening the database, but I'm guessing you're opening one that is included in your app bundle?  If so, you'll first need to copy the database into your app's Documents directory, because the application bundle is read-only.

You can get the path to the Documents directory with this:

`[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: yes i have done that as if i insert a new data that get saved in database but if i try to modify the existing data and then save it it doesn't works i get the same old data i was trying to modify...

Comment: i tried using break point and it breaks at:
[objectToEdit setValue:txtField.text forKey:self.keyOfTheFieldToEdit];